# how to remove inner brackets from arraylist object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, arraylist, iterator

I just want remove one extra brackets from below arrayList:

```
[
{
"small":"https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?",
"medium":"https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?",
"big":"https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?"
},
[
{
"small":"https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?",
"medium":"https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?",
"big":"https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?"
}
]
]

to 

[
{
"small":"https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?",
"medium":"https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?",
"big":"https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?"
},
{
"small":"https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?",
"medium":"https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?",
"big":"https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?"
}
]
```

### please help me to solve this.....thanks

................................................

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

It takes your original array and [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element to a new array. If an original element is an array(it has the 'extra brackets'), then instead of copying the value across, it copies the first element of that array only, effectively 'removing the brackets'. I assume that is what you are looking for.

```js
var a = [
    {
        "small": "https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?",
        "medium": "https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?",
        "big": "https://www.googleapis.com/photo.png?"
    },
    [
        {
            "small": "https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?",
            "medium": "https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?",
            "big": "https://www.googleapis.com/Jenner.jfif?"
        }
    ]
];

a = a.map(elem => {
    if (elem.constructor === Array) {
        return elem[0];
    } else {
        return elem;
    }
});

console.log(a);
```